# How to nest a glowing cube inside a larger cube in and render using Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor, edges, effects

[image]Hello I’m trying to make an effect like the red cubes in this scene but I can’t get the same effect. So far I’ve tried using a bigger glass cube and a small cube with an emission shader inside of the bigger cube.

Comment: there is a lot of things that are being used in this scene, things like emission in the cube's wireframe, volume scatter and absorption, noise texture and maybe using glass isn't the best idea, because in cycles its really hard to get a good glass effect with the default glass shader. Just search more about nodes and play with them, it will help you.

Comment: Could you link a node setup or blend file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## One object, one material solution

[image: final]

### Overview

For this method to work you will need to use current Master branch of Blender 2.79 or 2.8. You can find them here: https://builder.blender.org/download/

This is because we will be using **Bevel** node for edge detection. Without it there are some workarounds in Blender 2.79b like for example using **Bevel** modifier and second material for bevels.

### Nodes

[image: nodes]

Let's break it down to the most interesting parts.

**Inner Cube**

This is my dumb version of clipping vectors. What it does it basically using **Color Ramps** to clip axis vectors from left/right, top/bottom, and front/back to make smaller cube inside mesh. So two for X, Y and Z. You can tweak them in the same manner to get smaller or bigger cube. Those **Color Ramps**.

**Volume Noise**

It's noise. In **Volume**. Added to the **Inner Cube**. Nothing much here except that you will need to use grey color for one of the handles to make it darker than cube itself.

**Edge Mask**

This is why we need **Master** branch. We are using here **Bevel** node to detect edges and use it for mixing **Glass** with **Emission**.

**Glass and Edge**

Nothing fancy here. A bit optimized **Glass** shader and **Emission** for edges. Remember to use small **Roughness** value. I don't know if it's a bug or 'feature' but without it **Master** and 2.8 are going nuts with simple **Glass**.

Comment: Very nice job! I though this is literally only possible with the volumetric node.

Comment: @Amir Did you mean Principled Volume?

Comment: Sorry, yes that's what I meant.

Comment: @Amir so in this case, as far as I tested this one, it's just built in 'node group' of things which are existing in Blender for a long time. It looks like nothing more than Volume Scatter, Volume Absorbtion, Emission, Blackbody and Attribute nodes. It's nice and convenient though ;)

Comment: @user61431 if this answer was good enough, you can accept it and up vote ;) I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @user61431 Don't' forget to approve cgslav's post as answer if you think this is what you were looking for. Click on the checkmark next to this post and select it as answer. Also, you may consider up voting other answers if you find them useful still.

Answer (score 3):

Emission shaders are also volumetric. You can create the smaller cube proceedurally to have a glowing volume inside:

[image]

Comment: Basically same thing I did. With less Color Ramps ;)

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't have posted if I saw your post. I was doing a few things at once and took my time there and I did not notice your answer.

Comment: The more the better ;) Out of curiosity, whats the reason to use Combine XYZ as a part of Vector Add? I saw this method couple of times before but I can't comprehend what is going on there.

Comment: I just don't like the vector mapping node. It is huge, has no inputs and gets in the way all the time, at least visually. It distracts me. That's all - no real reason. The combine node is only for the values to be visible at a glance. I have a vector mapping node group with all inputs that I use ( https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/83465 ) , but I didn't want to introduce unnecessary confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert but this is the closest I could get using a combination of Principled Volumetric/BSDF shaders and emission shaders. I'm sure experts in Cycles rendering can combine the nodes in a better way so that you'll get the same exact effects.

To be able to use the Principled Volumetric shader you need to download/compile one of the latest experimental builds of Blender 2.79 (maybe from August 2018 onward). The Volumetric Shader is not available in 2.79b. You can download the experimental builds of Blender from [here](https://builder.blender.org/download/). Here's the final result with 18 samples in preview mode:

[image]

Here's the node setup for the outer cube:

[image]

And here's the node setup for the inner cube:

[image]

And here's the *.blend* file:

[image]